# Other than complications related to pregnancy, does zika pose any adult health risks?

Tags: virus, mosquito

Mosquito bites have [a host of potential issues.](http://www.mosquito.org/mosquito-borne-diseases) If there is no chance I will become pregnant, should the potential for zika cause me anymore concern about mosquito bites then all of the other things they can carry?

Answer (score 2):

For adults, Zika virus is like flu. Apart from fever and maybe nausea, you shouldn't have to worry.

Edit: since it seems sources are of bad need, here is one confirmation from a very recent study (Petersen 2016).

Source : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1201971216000217

Comment: References to back this up?